# Surgery along knots and connected sum

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, surgery-theory

Denote $S^3_{p/q}(K)$ by performing $p/q$-surgery along a knot $K$ in $S^3$.

Let $K$ and $J$ be two arbitrary oriented non-trivial knots in $S^3$. Is there a nice relation between surgery on the connected sum of knots and the connected sum of their surgeries?

More explicitly, let say, do we have the following homeomorphism: $$S^3_{p/q}(K \# J) \approx S^3_{p/q}(K) \ \# \ S^3_{p/q}(J).$$

It might be *false*. Does this homeomorphism hold for integral surgeries?

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful, but the connect-sum of the surgeries is the surgery on the *link* given by the disjoint union of the two knots separated by a sphere.

Comment: Are you interested in the left-hand side or the right-hand side of your hopeful equivalence?   Sawin has given you the answer in case the right-hand side is your interest.  The left-hand side is often a prime manifold, so it has no connect-sum decomposition at all.  If you have not read a set of introductory notes on 3-manifold theory, the Hatcher or  Jaco notes would help you think through this sort of question.

Answer (score 10):

If $p \neq \pm 1$ then this can't happen, because the homology groups of the two sides would be different. I suspect it can't happen at all unless one of the knots is trivial; this would follow from the well-known *cabling conjecture*. If both knots are non-trivial, then the right side is a reducible manifold, so you would need that at least one summand is the $3$-sphere, which doesn't happen by the resolution of the property P conjecture. The cabling conjecture asserts that a knot with a reducible surgery is a $(p,q)$ cable, the surgery would be a $pq/1$ surgery, and one of the summands would be a lens space $L(pq,1)$. But a non-trivial connected sum is not a cable of another knot.

In general, surgery doesn't commute with connected sums, so one wouldn't expect an equality of the sort you're asking about. The sphere along which the connected sum is done doesn't yield a sphere in the surgered manifold; it yields a torus.

Comment: The homeomorphism always exists for $\mp 1$-surgeries?

Comment: No: I wrote "I suspect it can't happen at all unless one of the knots is trivial". The homeomorphism you are asking about would contradict a widely believed conjecture.

Comment: @DannyRuberman: Gordon and Luecke have proved that if a surgery along a knot in $S^3$ is reducible, then it contains a lens space summand, so $p$ cannot be 1. (This is Theorem 3 in *Knots are determined by their complements*.)

Comment: @MarcoGolla Thanks--I thought I knew that statement but didn't have the chance to chase it down.